# How to get non expanded matrix from sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have this sympy code:

```
# Define matrices and vectors using the more straightforward approach
A_matrix = sp.MatrixSymbol('A', 3, 2).as_explicit()
x_vector = sp.MatrixSymbol('x', 2, 1).as_explicit()
y_vector = sp.MatrixSymbol('y', 3, 1).as_explicit()


# Define the summation index symbol
i = sp.Symbol('i', integer=True)

# Redefine the function using the sum notation
f_sum = sp.Sum((A_matrix * x_vector - y_vector)[i, 0]**2, (i, 0, 2))

# Compute the gradient using the sum notation
gradient_f_sum = [f_sum.diff(x_vector[j, 0]) for j in range(2)]

# Simplify the gradient expression
gradient_f_sum_simplified = [sp.simplify(expr) for expr in gradient_f_sum]
gradient_f_sum_simplified
```

which gives me this as output:

[image]

How do I get the non-expanded form of this equation? Which should be: `(2A.(X.xvector-yvector)`

---

Update 1:

Removing the `.as_explicit`:

```
# Define matrices and vectors using the more straightforward approach
A_matrix = sp.MatrixSymbol('A', 3, 2)
x_vector = sp.MatrixSymbol('x', 2, 1)
y_vector = sp.MatrixSymbol('y', 3, 1)


# Define the summation index symbol
i = sp.Symbol('i', integer=True)

# Redefine the function using the sum notation
f_sum = sp.Sum((A_matrix * x_vector - y_vector)[i, 0]**2, (i, 0, 2))

# Compute the gradient using the sum notation
gradient_f_sum = [f_sum.diff(x_vector[j, 0]) for j in range(2)]

# Simplify the gradient expression
gradient_f_sum_simplified = [sp.simplify(expr) for expr in gradient_f_sum]
gradient_f_sum_simplified
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is using `as_explicit`:

```
In [17]: A_matrix = sp.MatrixSymbol('A', 3, 2)

In [18]: x_vector = sp.MatrixSymbol('x', 2, 1)

In [19]: y_vector = sp.MatrixSymbol('y', 3, 1)

In [20]: f = A_matrix * x_vector - y_vector

In [21]: f
Out[21]: -y + A⋅x

In [22]: f.as_explicit()
Out[22]: 
⎡A₀₀⋅x₀₀ + A₀₁⋅x₁₀ - y₀₀⎤
⎢                       ⎥
⎢A₁₀⋅x₀₀ + A₁₁⋅x₁₀ - y₁₀⎥
⎢                       ⎥
⎣A₂₀⋅x₀₀ + A₂₁⋅x₁₀ - y₂₀⎦
```

Don't use `as_explicit` if you don't want to expand this out like that and then you can get the result in terms of matrix symbols:

```
In [23]: f_sum = f.T * f

In [24]: f_sum
Out[24]: 
⎛  T    T  T⎞           
⎝-y  + x ⋅A ⎠⋅(-y + A⋅x)

In [25]: f_sum.diff(x_vector)
Out[25]: 
   T           
2⋅A ⋅(-y + A⋅x)
```

Comment: If you would remove the . as_explicit() from my example, you would still get an expression that is expanded.

Comment: That is because you also use explicit indexing to define `f_sum`.